# Error en la conexión: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'enramada'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Tengo el siguiente código para crear una conexión con una BD que se llama 'enramada' en Java y MySQL:

```
public class conectar {

    Connection conect = null;

    public Connection conexion() {
        try {
            //Registramos el driver:
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Especificamos la URL de conexion:
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/enramada";
            //Especificamos el usuario y el password:
            String usuario = "root";
            String password = "";

            //Abrimos la conexion con la bd:
            conect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión Exitosa ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error en la conexión:\n"+ e);

        }
        return conect;
    }
}
```

Y me manda el siguiente error:

```
Error en la conexión: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'enramada'
```

y la BD si esta creada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pongo el nombre de otra BD si se conecta, pero con esta que quiero no. ¿que puede ser?.

Tiene todos los permisos esta BD[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en Java tengo esta clase para listar miS BD:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class mysqlTestMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String myConnectionString =
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306?" +
                "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SHOW DATABASES");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Ya hice una BD vacia en PHPmyADMIN y cuando trato de listarlas en java no me aparece y no se a que se debe. Adjunto fotos para que vean.
en PHPmyADMIN si me aparece la bd enramada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en WorkBench si me lista tambien la bd enramada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en la conexión que hago en Java no me la lista y me lista otra bd que no tengo en Workbench ni en PHPmyADMIN[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes entrar a la consola para listar todas las BD a las que puede acceder el usuario? (show databases) , agregalo a tu pregunta para verificar este caso particular. Podrias crear una BD vacia para ver si se conecta a esa otra?

Comment: ¿como listo todas las bd para saber los permisos?, ya hice varias BD en blanco y si se conecta a ellas, sin embargo no se porque con esta en particular no.

Comment: ya añadí una imagen donde se ven todos los permisos con los que cuenta el usuario y se ve, que tiene todos los privilegios.

Comment: Extraño... ¿y si pones `localhost`  en vez de `127.0.0.1` en la cadena de conexión? ¿Verificaste que el puerto es `3306`?

Comment: Puede ser que tus otras bases de datos esté escuchando en otro puerto que no sea el `3306`. Puedes probar esto desde phpMyAdmin para verificar el puerto `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';`  o bien desde la consola: `netstat -tlnp` para ver los puertos.

Comment: ya lo verifique y en phpMyAdmin el puerto es el 3306, entonces desconozco que puede ser

Comment: Parece que lo que está funcionando son las bases de datos que tienes en Workbench y no las que tienes en phpMyAdmin. Si creas la bd en Workbench es posible que entonces sí conecte.

Comment: @A.Cedano la solución fue reinstalar WAMPSERVER, gracias

Comment: Sonaba a eso, a un conflicto en alguna parte. Creo que una pequeña nota al respecto en la respuesta de @JulioCesarCervantesMartinez sería mejor solución, ya que su respuesta te ha ayudado a darte cuenta de que no se mostraban las BD que esperabas realmente y sería una forma de valorar su esfuerzo en la respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba este codigo para listar todas tus BD:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class mysqlTestMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String myConnectionString =
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306?" +
                "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SHOW DATABASES");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Esto debe mostrar todas las BD's disponibles, verifica que aparecen todas tus BD's, copia y pega el nombre de la base de datos que necesitas si aparece, podria ser un error tipografico(un caracter oculto por ejemplo)

Comment: Si puedes comenta cuál era el problema @IsidroMartinez

Comment: Ya probé el código y hay varias cosas raras, varias bases de datos que eh borrado con WorkBench y/o PHPMyAdmin aún me las lista y la base de datos `enramada`no me la muestra. Pero si hago la consulta en Workbench si me muestra la base de datos `enramada` ¿sabes que podría ser? Ya actualice la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya actualice mi pregunta. espero puedan ayudarme,llevo toda la mañana y no puedo resolverlo.

Comment: Solo se me ocurre lo que te comentaban, que sean puertos diferentes, es decir, que tu base de datos no sea accesible porque esta en otro servidor

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue: primero desinstalé mysql, que había instalado con otra aplicación, ya después deje el puerto principal de mysql de xampp con el 3306 puesto que en otro no la vincula "comprobado", y por último en el código quitar pasword root porque de otra forma no abre.